# Bookmarklet to grab info from current url and insert into new one

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'd like a bookmarklet that takes info from my current url (like these):

https://www.themoviedb.org/tv/88396-falcon-winter-soldier 
https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/64688-21-jump-street 
https://www.themoviedb.org/person/7447-alec-baldwin

Extracts just id portion, the first set of numbers (88396, 64688, 7447, etc) and appends it to a new url like this:

https://webhookurl.com/webhook?movieID=(id from url)

Which opens in a background tab ideally.

I'm super new to javascript, been trying to cobble something together from similar answers on here but unable to figure it out. Any help is very much appreciated.

update: thanks to some help here with the regex and tinkering until i got the other tab thing to work, i now have a finished bookmarklet that works. thanks

ud2: changed again to 1. match urls with no '-film-name' after the id number, and also to open in a small new window rather than new tab so i can easily close after the webhook is accepted and it doesn't obstruct my view of the page

```
javascript:(function(){ open(window.location.toString().replace(/^https:\/\/www.themoviedb.org\/.*?\/([0-9]+)-?.*/, 'https://fakewebhook.com/webhook?movieID=$1'), "", "width=400, height=200");})()
```

Comment: You may use regular expression. Please find the answer below. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use regex to form the new url from the given url.

```
'https://www.themoviedb.org/tv/88396-falcon-winter-soldier'.replace(/^https:\/\/www.themoviedb.org\/tv\/([0-9]+)-.+/, 'https://webhookurl.com/webhook?movieID=$1')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with the regex. One of the variations I tried to replicate also relied on .replace 

I wasn't able to get it to do anything except re-load the page. I swapped out your regex for the mangled one i tried to write, but it still only reloads the page, not opens a new one with the target url

this is what I currently have

`javascript:(function() {window.location=window.location.toString().replace(/^https:\/\/www.themoviedb.org\/tv\/([0-9]+)-.+/, 'https://webhookurl.com/webhook?movieID=$1');})() `

Comment: nevermind, I got it! I didn't pay attention enough to see you wrote the regex to only match tv urls. I was able to get it to do what I want now

Thanks for your help! (finished code is edited into first post)